# design advice : Entity Framework useful with stored procedures?

Tags: entity-framework, design-patterns, stored-procedures

I am new to .NET and early in the design process of a front-end application for a database, and looking for some advice.

I am not sure I get it...

The DB is very strongly normalized, but provides lots of stored procedures to abstract the logical model (ex. Select sproc returns one data set from multiple tables closely reflecting the business object, Insert/Update sprocs to multiple tables, etc..)

How should I design the DAL ?
I'm not sure what the benefit of the Entity Framework is in this context.
When generated, it reflects the normalized DB schema rather than an abstraction of it. 
Or if I map the sprocs to generate it (which requires some work since the T-SQL in the sprocs is dynamic and with joins), I get the business objects alright but can't see the benefit of it : the entities represent to a single 'abstract' table, and not a set of entities with Datarelations, the sprocs handles the calls to multiple tables. It seems more work to map the generated change events to the sprocs than to call the sprocs directly.

What am I missing ?

Thanks,

Michael.

Comment: I can't really figure out what you really want to do.. The first question is how would you like to define your entity model - do it first and then adjust the database to reflect it. EF won't do any magic, mapping the db straight to entities is a complex enough task, so don't expect too much.

Comment: A concrete example : I have Person and Organization tables, each of them is linked to an Address table in a many-to-many relationship (intermediate tables with additional properties). The DB logic and sprocs only expose (or update) : Person table, Org table, PersonAddress table and OrgAddress, abstracting the intermediate tables (same logic for phones, etc..). I though of just creating seperate ST datasets : Person (+ linked tables), Organisation, etc.. but then I forget about EF ? Sorry, I am obviously a beginner...

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with the EF, but the designer won't help you; it doesn't know how to derive an entity type from a stored proc signature. You would need to write the EDMX by hand. CTP 4 code-first *may* be easier, but I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I think I'm starting to be on the right track.
The following articles were very helpful :

[Entity Framework Modeling: Table Per Hierarchy Inheritance](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/)

see also : Entity Framework Modeling : Entity Splitting

To be clear, what I wanted was to abstract the DB schema in the EF model.
(I didn't want any entity representing 'nothing', like a many-to-many relationship).

Besides these modeling techniques, I used views to generate the EF model, and added sprocs for CRUD.

As I said, I am a beginner. Let me know if I am on a wrong track...